# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate: Postgres. Wrong column type in abc_user for uuid. Found: bpchar, expected: char(32)

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I have a project with a bit strange mapping:

```
<class name="com.xxx.yyy.User" table="abc_user">
    <id name="uuid" type="string">
        <column name="uuid" not-null="true" sql-type="char(32)"/>
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
```

The mapping is passing validation for Oracle and Microsoft SQL, but failed for Postgres with an exception:

> Wrong column type in abc_user for uuid. Found: bpchar, expected:
>   char(32)

I see the reason (Postgres internally transform char type to bpchar). But have no idea how to fix it, because hibernate mapping is using for Oracle, Postgres & MS SQL databases. So I can't change mapping.

I supposed that I have to fix it at dialect level (as I did for Oracle dialect)

```
registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARCHAR, "clob" );
```

but this approach a will not work for `Types.CHAR` (it's an alias for char(1)).

Any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Hi, isn't the `registerColumnType` function able to accept the length of the parameter? maybe, could you try this? `registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, 32, "test");`

Comment: I did, no result. Based on PostgreSQL81Dialect I see that char is for single (i.e. char(1)) value (registerColumnType(1, "char(1)")).

Comment: aa, you're right. I just checked the source code. then, how about you override the dialect and in the constructor you replace the registered column type with something like this `registerColumnType( Types.CHAR, "char($1)" );`?

Comment: The same exception. I believe that Hibernate use Types.CHAR only for column with length=1 :(

Comment: PgJDBC reports the underlying PostgreSQL type in JDBC metadata. While PgJDBC could report `character(n)` (the SQL-standard spelling) instead of `bpchar`, that'd then confuse apps that used `bpchar` directly, and wouldn't help apps that expected `char(n)` instead of `character(n)`. I think this is really something the Hibernate PostgreSQL dialect needs to take care of. BTW, for bonus complexity, `char(1)` is different to `"char"` (with quotes).

Comment: don't use `char(n)` in the first place https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29